# How to run a fsm model forever

Tags: python, transition, automata, state-machine

I am using python transitions module ([link](http://github.com/pytransitions/transitions)) to create finite state machine.

How do I run this finite state machine forever?

Bascically what I want is a fsm model which can stay "idle" when there is no more event to trigger.

For examplel, in example.py:

```
state = [ 'A', B', 'C']
transtion = [ A->B->C]

if name == 'main':
machine = Machine(state, transition, initial='A')**
print(machine.state)**
```

If I to run this machine in a python program, it will go into state 'A', print the current state, and the program will then exit immediately.

So my question is how can I keep it running forever when there is nothing to trigger a transition? Shall I implement a loop or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Hi all, I forget to mention in the quesiton that I am using python transitions module. https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions

Comment: What you provide is not working python code... except for that you might want to look at `while` cycles paired with `threading`

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is a little broad I have to assume one or two things. 
For instance it is not stated how you plan to provide events to be processed for the machine.

> Shall I implement a loop or is there any other way to do so?

Well, it depends on what kind of event mechanism you plan to use. Some implementations will do that for do, others wont.

You could for instance couple a machine to an event queue where you have to take care of the event loop yourself. In the example below I feed random numbers to a model which will use a machine to change states depending on the passed number.

```
from transitions import Machine
from threading import Thread
import random
import time

try:
    from Queue import Queue
except ImportError:  # Module has been renamed in Python 3
    from queue import Queue


class Model(Thread):

    def __init__(self, event_queue):
        self.event_queue = event_queue
        # has to be called whenever something inherits from Thread
        super(Model, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            event = self.event_queue.get(block=True)
            # 0 will end the event loop
            if event == 0:
                return
            # if the passed number is even, switch to Even state
            elif event % 2 == 0:
                self.even()
            # switch to Odd state otherwise
            else:
                self.odd()

states = ['Even', 'Odd']
transitions = [['even', '*', 'Even'],
               ['odd', '*', 'Odd']]

event_queue = Queue()
model = Model(event_queue)
machine = Machine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial='Even')
model.start()

for n in random.sample(range(1, 20), 5):
    event_queue.put(n)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Number {0} was passed to the model which is now in state {1}".format(n, model.state))

# shut down model thread
event_queue.put(0)
```

The model will actually *block* until it receives the next event and will shutdown the moment it receives the event `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the while loop. Just create a new variable, set it to 0. To use the forever loop, just do a while loop like this

```
forever_variable = 0
while forever_variable == 0:
    (code to be run forever)
```